# I want to calculate total and average of data from text file using C++

Tags: c++

I want to calculate total and average of data from text file using C++.
Here is my code and text file.
This code is not showing anything on run

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

string double2string(double);
double string2double(string);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

fstream dfile;  

string s1;
string amount;
double damount;
double sum = 0;


dfile.open(argv[1]);


    dfile >> amount;

    damount = string2double(amount);

    while(damount){

    sum = sum + damount;

}

string total = double2string(sum);


dfile.clear();

dfile.close();

cout << total; 

return 0;
}
```

Functions to convert string to double and double to string

```
string double2string(double d){
ostringstream outstr; 
outstr << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(10) << d; 
return outstr.str(); 
};

double string2double(string s1){ 
istringstream instr(s1); 
double n; 
instr >> n; 
return n; 
}
```

Here is my text file "data.txt"

```
  234
  456
  789
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried to run your code? Is it returning any errors?

Comment: `while(damount){ sum = sum + damount; }` is an infinite loop.

Comment: It would be simpler to just read the numbers as numbers, not strings that get converted to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a while loop. You're reading in only one line, so you need to make sure that you keep reading in lines until the end of the file.

Also, you might want to use a standard library function: `std::stoi` is the C++11 and onward version that works for `std::string`, but `std::atoi` from `<cstdlib>` works just as well with `std::string.c_str()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

//Compile with C++11; -std=c++11
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::fstream file;

    //Open the file
    file.open(argv[1]);
    std::string buffer = "";
    int sum = 0;
    int n = 0;

    //Check for file validity, and keep reading in line by line.
    if (file.good()) {
        while (file >> buffer) {
            n = std::stoi(buffer);
            sum += n;
        }

        std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "File: " << argv[1] << "is not valid." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```